# <unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: 'COCOAPODS'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

Can anyone help me with this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHNMb.png) why it ask for cocoapods file or directory?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem, and found that while tweaking some compiler flags, the build settings got a bit scrambled.

To fix it, check to see if you have "COCOAPODS" in any of your **Project**>**Build Settings**>**Other Swift Flags**, and remove it:

[Bad line in "Other Swift Flags"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Csr3E.png)

Answer (score 2):

To me was because I forgot to put "-D" before my custom swift flag

Answer (score 1):

`pod setup` or `pod repo update` then `pod install`

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error because when I duplicate my main `Target`, I added a new compiler flag on:

**Project** -> **Build Settings** -> **Other Swift Flags**

And if I remove the "COCOAPODS" flags, another errors appears.

The error occurs when I added a custom flags. To solve that, the right way to add a custom flags is with quotation marks, for example:

[image]